# struct.error: required argument is not an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python code:

```
velocity = 0
rotation = 0
vr = velocity + (rotation/2)
vl = velocity - (rotation/2)
cmd = struct.pack(">Bhh", 145, vr, vl)
```

I am dealing with the following error:

```
File "control.py", line 125, in __init__  
cmd = struct.pack(">Bhh", 145, vr, vl)  
struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

Comment: What is `self`? It's not defined anywhere in the code. In particular, what are the values of `self.callbackKeyUp`, `self.callbackKeyDown`, `self.callbackKeyLeft`, and `self.callbackKeyRight`? You should determine what the values are and then modify the example code so that it doesn't reference `self`. Are the increments and decrements even necessary to reproduce?

Comment: I made it simpler for you, @jpmc26 since you requested :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the [incorrect formats](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) for the arguments you are passing in: `h` format indicates storing of `short`, while the value you are passing in, i.e. `vr` and `vl`, look like `double`s.

Consider typecasting them to `int` or using `">Bdd"` format.