# Using Struct.pack format for string value

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

I want to see my packet this format: `b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06`

But I am seeing this format: `\x00\x01\x06\x01\x03\` How can I see this?

```
encoder=struct.pack('5B',int(trnsact,16),int(ident,16),int(length_data,16),int(unitid,16),int(func_code,16))
```

That is my values:

```
transaction_id=0x00
ident_id=0x01
length_data=0x06
unitid=0x01
funccode=0x03
```

And `type(transaction_id)=string` (so I turn the my string value to integer)

If I using this type:

`encoder=struct.pack('5B',transaction,ident,unitid,funcode)`

I have this error: `struct.error: required argument is not an integer`

I am very confused about this please help me

Comment: I updated my answer and check it in Python3.6 without any error. You can try this on [Python3 online IDE](https://repl.it/repls/NearKindlyBudgetrange). I dealing to error with using `int(hex, 16)` to `struct.pack()` instead, it's confusing!

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421197/struct-error-required-argument-is-not-an-integer), seems the same problem.

Comment: If your problem solved by my answer, consider please the vote up to it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Modbus-TCP:

- `transaction` is 2Byte == Short == `H`
- `identifier` is 2Byte == Short == `H`
- `length` is 2Byte == Short == `H`
- `unitid` is 1Byte == `B`
- `fcode` is 1Byte == `B`
- `reg_addr` is 2Byte == Short == `H`
- `count` is 2Byte == Short == `H`

---

Thus, the format in your case will be `>HHHBB` or `>3H2B`:

```
import struct

transaction = 0x00
ident = 0x01
length_data = 0x06
unitid = 0x01
fcode = 0x03

encoder = struct.pack('>HHHBB', transaction, ident, length_data, unitid, fcode)
print(encoder)
```

Out:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06\x01\x03'
```

---

[UPDATE]:

Anyway, if you want to have like this (`b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06`), doing as the following:

```
import struct

transaction = 0x00  # Used with replacement.
ident = 0x01  # Used with replacement.
length_data = 0x06  # Used.
unitid = 0x01  # Not used.
fcode = 0x03  # Not used.

encoder = struct.pack('>3H', ident, transaction, length_data)
print(encoder)
```

Out:

```
b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06'
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `B` is Unsigned Byte.
- `H` is Unsigned Short.
- `<` is Little Endian.
- `>` is Big Endian.
- I test these snippet codes with *Python2.7* and *Python3.6*.
- You can also check these snippet code in the [Python3_online_IDE](https://repl.it/repls/NearKindlyBudgetrange).
- However, if you encountered with the `struct.error: required argument is not an integer` error, using with `int(<hex-str>, 16)`