# Python struct.pack: required argument is not an integer. Input are all integers

Tags: python, struct, udp

I use a modified version of https://github.com/houluy/UDP to parse and send raw UDP packets. However, sometimes it randomly triggers an exception on  struct.pack(). It does not seem to be related to a certain packet, but when I increase the packet rate the error seems to be thrown.

Relevant code:

```
src_port = src_addr[1]
dest_port = dest_addr[1]

udp_length = 8 + len(data)

checksum = 0
pseudo_header = struct.pack('!BBH', zero, protocol, udp_length)
pseudo_header = src_ip + dest_ip + pseudo_header
try:
    udp_header = struct.pack('!4H', src_port, dest_port, udp_length, checksum)
except struct.error as err:
    print(err)
    print("Port: " + str(src_port) + " = " + str(type(src_port)))
    print("DestPort: " + str(dest_port) + " = " + str(type(src_port)))
    print("Len: " + str(udp_length) + " = " + str(type(src_port)))
    print("Checksum: " + str(checksum) + " = " + str(type(src_port)))
```

struct.pack throws the error required argument is not an integer. As such I print the types in the except clause to verify what is going wrong. I get the following output:

```
required argument is not an integer
Port: 123 = <class 'int'>
DestPort: 123 = <class 'int'>
Len: 16 = <class 'int'>
Checksum: 0 = <class 'int'>
```

I don't have the slightest clue what is going wrong here. If I were to explicitly cast the value to integers to be sure with the following line, the exact same thing happens

```
udp_header = struct.pack('!4H', int(src_port), int(dest_port), int(udp_length), int(checksum))
```

Perhaps I am missing something, but I don't have any clue what is going wrong here. Running Python 3.6.7 on CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804.

Comment: Your print messages all use `str(type(src_port))` instead of the type of the actual argument, i.e. `dest_port`, `udp_length`, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [struct.error: required argument is not an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421197/struct-error-required-argument-is-not-an-integer)

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes because you cannot combine a print string with non-string literals. So I request the type and convert that type representation to a string in order to visually print it. What would you suggest to do differently?

Comment: I would suggest you print the type of the _correct variable_.  e.g. the second message prints the __value__ of `dest_port` but the __type__ of `src_port`.

Comment: @JohnGordon oh my, I only noticed this now. Perhaps this was the clear oversight that I was missing. Still weird that after converting to int with int() as in the last line, it still did not work. It's been solved for now, but thanks a lot for hinting me to this obvious error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. It appeared that the dest_port was a string after all. Why Python still printed it was an int type is still a mystery to me. After after explicit conversion to int() the problem remained. Changing the data at the source to int() has solved the problem. This is still odd behavior I'd say.